# How does a large electric switch different from small?

Tags: current, switches, electric-machine

Why do some electric appliances require to have a large electric switch to turn them on or off? If I use a small switch where a large switch is required, would there be potential possibility of getting a shock? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Larger switches allow the contacts to be further separated when switching off. If you switch a large current off the contacts will draw an arc that will burn the contacts. In AC that's not as bad as in DC, because the zero-crossing will extinguish the arc. But in DC the arc can persist for longer time, and will only extinguish by pulling the contacts far enough apart.

High voltage switches (110V/230V) are larger because they need a better isolation between the voltage at the contacts and the user operated lever.

Answer (score 2):

Worst case result of using a too small switch is death. Not something you'd expect to happen every day, and you'd probably only have it happen to you once in a lifetime.

A switch size is partially set my marketing and appearances and partially by technical considerations. Conductors need to be large enough to carry the potential fault currents without overheating - and to be able to carry the long term rated currents with limited heat rise. Heating leads to early failure.

Larger currents tend to require larger conductors, bigger contacts, higher contact pressures, larger off-state clearances and an ability to deal with possible fault currents. In some AC domestic applications a fault can cause seriously large (by most standards) currents to flow. Potential fault currents may be 100's to thousands of amps. If a switch interrupts a high current it MUST be able to do so cleanly. A too small switch may experience arcing and failure to disconnect the faulty circuit. This requirement is not as severe as for a fuse or a circuit breaker but is still a consideration.

Switch voltage ratings tend to increases with size.

Comment: Are mains switches ever designed to deal with any significant fault current? Most normal switches (as opposed to breakers) simply specify rated current and sometimes a maximum inrush current. I think it is assumed that fault currents will be interrupted by a protective element and not manually by a switch.